# Proguard rule for Fragment class

Tags: android, proguard

I'd like to create a proguard rule to keep two fragment classes. I can get the rule to work by keeping all fragment classes, but want to narrow it down to just two specific classes. Is this possible?

If I add the proguard rule `-keep class * extends androidx.fragment.app.Fragment {}`, it works. But I want to narrow this down to include *only* `Screen1PreferencesFragment` and `Screen2PreferencesFragment` classes in the below code snippet.

```
CustomActivity.kt

class CustomActivity : AppCompatActivity(), PreferenceFragmentCompat.OnPreferenceStartFragmentCallback {
   ...

    class Screen1PreferencesFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {
        override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.screen1_preferences, rootkey)
        }
    }

    class Screen2PreferencesFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {
        override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.screen2_preferences, rootKey)
        }
    }
   ...
}
```

Comment: Why do you think you need a ProGuard rule to keep those Fragment classes?

Comment: minification is removing them and I need them. Any idea how to focus the proguard rule to them?

Comment: Where are you using them such that minification is removing them? Can you include how you are using these classes in your question?

Comment: The classes are part of a settings hierarchy.

Comment: Those should be kept automatically. Can you include where you're using those classes?

Comment: They are not. I really don't want to derail this question and I don't want to go into details of the application. To get back on track, I just have a goal of narrowing down the proguard rule. Hoping someone can help with that.